# Assembler: Using "Flat assembler" how do I produce EXE files (compile, link..)?

Tags: x86, assembly, fasm

I'm using FASM to compile a small piece of code:

```
  mov ah,4ch
  mov al,00
  int 21h
```

I click Run -> Compile, and what I get is a .BIN file.
sorry for the noobish question but why don't I get an OBJ, or an EXE file, and what is this BIN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The BIN is a binary file, You need to check the command line options that you used to pass to FASM. According to the [documentation](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.4) the default format is a flat binary file. To quote from the documentation, section 2.4:

```
Default output format is a flat binary file, it can also be selected by using 
format binary directive. This directive can be followed by the as keyword and 
the quoted string specifying the default file extension for the output file. 
Unless the output file name was specified from the command line, assembler will
use this extension when generating the output file.
```

So I think your code should look like this:

```
.use32
.format pe console
mov ah,4ch
mov al,00
int 21h
```

**Edit:** I just realized after hitting Save, that it was 16 bit registers used...

```
.use16
.format MZ
mov ah,4ch
mov al,00
int 21h
```

Answer (score 3):

Ya know, they have their own forum.
http://board.flatassembler.net/